# Implement a searchview using navigation components

Tags: kotlin, androidx, searchview, android-architecture-navigation

I have a MainActivity which has a default toolbar with items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/contact_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_aboutus"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="About us"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And i override onCreateOptionsMenu && onOptionsItemSelected to give functionality to my buttons.

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.contact_search -> {
              val searchIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity,SearchAccountActivity::class.java)
              startActivity(searchIntent)
            }

            R.id.action_aboutus -> {
                val logoutIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AboutActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(logoutIntent)
            }

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

MainActivity has  containerFragment and the first fragment is NOT the contacts, so if i want to search the contacts i open a new activity. However i want to use the functionality of the searchView that gives automatically set up in the toolbar and i wan to do it in a seperate fragment which it will be under the MainActivity.

How can i do this? Is there anything read in the androidx library?
Thank you